# How can I check if the key exists in a std::map and get the map::iterator in if condition?

Tags: c++

I'd like to define the variable in condition expression so that the variable scope would be within the `if` clause. This works fine,

`if (int* x = new int(123)) { }`

When I was trying to do a similar thing with map::iterator,

`if ((map<string, Property>::iterator it = props.find(PROP_NAME)) != props.end()) { it->do_something(); }`

I got `error: expected primary-expression before ‘it’`

What makes the difference between `int*` and `map::iterator`?

Comment: Please don't allocate dynamic memory like this. You are wide open to a memory leak in case of an exception. Either use a smart pointer, or consider whether a simple `int` needs to be in dynamic memory in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference between `int *` and `map::iterator` in that regard. There's a difference in the surrounding semantic constructs that you are using with `int *` and `map::iterator`, which is why one compiles and other doesn't.

With `if` you have a choice of either

```
if (declaration)
```

or

```
if (expression)
```

Declaration is not an expression. You can't use a declaration as a subexpression in a larger expression. You cannot use a declaration as a part of explicit comparison, which is exactly what you attempt to do.

For example, if you attempted to do the same thing with `int *`, like this

```
if ((int* x = new int(123)) != NULL)
```

the code would not not compile for exactly the same reasons your `map::iterator` code does not compile.

You have to use

```
if (int* x = new int(123))
```

or

```
int* x = new int(123);
if (x != NULL)
```

or

```
int* x;
if ((x = new int(123)) != NULL)
```

As you can see above, `int *` exhibits exactly the same behavior as `map::iterator`.

In your example, it is impossible to declare `it` and perform its comparison with `props.end()` in `if`s condition. You will have to use one of the above variants instead, i.e. either

```
map<string, Property>::iterator it = props.find(PROP_NAME);
if (it != props.end())
```

or

```
map<string, Property>::iterator it;
if ((it = props.find(PROP_NAME)) != props.end())
```

Choose whichever you like more.

P.S. Of course, formally you can also write

```
if (map<string, Property>::iterator it = props.find(PROP_NAME))
```

but it does not do what you want it to do (does not compare the iterator value to `props.end()`) and might not compile at all, since the iterator type is probably not convertible to `bool`.

Comment: Regarding 'Declaration is not an expression', what's the value of (int* x = new int(123))? That can be put in if()

Comment: @woodings: As I said above, this form is treated by a separate, dedicated branch of C++ language semantics. It is not an `if (expression)` branch, it is an `if (declaration)` branch. The language defines it separately. It basically says that the declared variable gets implicitly converted to `bool` and that value is used for making the branching decision. This does not turn a declaration into an expression and does not allow you to use declarations within other, bigger expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to limit it to a scope:

```
{
    auto it = props.find(PROP_NAME);
    if (it != props.end()) {
       it->do_something();
    }
}
```

Granted, this scope is not technically the "if scope", but should serve just as well for all practical intents and purposes.

As [AndreyT already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624322/533120) (+1), declaration can't transcend `(` and `)`, which you did not use for `int` but you did for the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Map iterators contain `first` and `second`, which point to the key and value, respectively. 
To access a member of the value, use `it->second.do_Something()`